# Bpmn - How to model an optional task

Tags: bpmn, camunda

[image]

After the Task 1 is completed, we need to spawn an optional task, based on a condition. The process completion does not depend on this optional task completion.

What is the correct way to design this model ?

Comment: No, that's not the right way. Should the optional task run before, or in parallel to task 2?

Comment: Parallel to task 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the desired behaviour can be modeled like this:

[image: BPMN Diagram]

After Task1 completes Task2 is triggered, if the optional Condition is true, the optional Task is triggered as well.
The Instance is terminated after Task2 is finished. If the optional Task was still active it will be terminated.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Modeling optional task in BPMN]

You should use conditional marker for the optional flow.
Exclusive gateway in your diagram will always execute mandatory Task 2, optional task will always be ignored even when the condition for its execution is true.

Parallel gateway can not be used as it will wait for the optional task to complete for successful merge.

Comment: But if Optional Task is completed before Task 2, that will trigger the end event of process, right? It must not.

Comment: That will happen if we use `Terminate End` event rather than `Standard End` event. A process finishes successfully once all started process activities have finished.

Comment: I would like the process to be completed as soon as Task 2 is completed, no mater if there is an active Optional Task. Is that possible ? That is what the client ask me to model, but maybe this makes no sense... and I should clarify with them the definition of a "Completed Process".

Answer (score 0):

Are conditional markers BPMN 2.0 ok? not even seen them before except they remind me good old UML.

I think this should be solved using a XOR gateway.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Using non-interrupting (message/signal/escalation) events will help your scenario.

Alternatively, using event subprocess in this process.

Let me know if you understand how to use it. Otherwise, I will draw an example for you

## UPDATE

NOTE: 
1. I am only using bpmn.io to draw example instead of Camunda. However, this is basic BPMN and I assume Camunda must have this type of model. I am only familiar with JBPM.

EXPLANATION: 
Basically, you don't really have to use message event. It can be signal/escalation depending on what scenarios you have. Theoretically, message event is used if there is an incoming message to create other activities and this event is the most common among the others. Yet, one thing you must consider is whether the event is interrupting or not. In your case, it doesn't interrupt, therefore I put non-interrupt message event.

Interrupt message event will abort the Task 1 immediately as soon as the event is triggered while non-interrupting is only adding additional task/event without aborting Task 1.

[image]

Hope this example helps.

Comment: Thanks for that ! Yes I would appreciate an example. I'm not used to event message/signal.

Comment: @hnandarusdy small information: bpmn.io is a product made by camunda so yes they got that type of model :)

Comment: Sorry this answer is very confusing. The important part is the terminating end-event. A non-interrupting Message/Escalation/etc event doesn't help and is just confusing.